# Delphi RAD Server raises error for registercomponents call

Tags: delphi, vcl

I wrote my own component, and it is working perfectly in a desktop application. But it will raise error "Invalid component registration" when I launch it in a RAD Server application.

It can be reproduced even if I don't use the component, just simply including the component file.

e.g

```pascal
type
  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    Fcaption : string;
  published
    property caption : string read Fcaption write fcaption;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('custom', [TTest]);
end;
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q to show how you launch your component in your RAD server.

Comment: Just build a simple RAD Server application, and then add this simple sample file into the project, run RAD Server application, it will raise "Invalid component registration"

Comment: Component registration is to be done only in design-time code, not in runtime code, so the line above should never appear in code that will *run in a RAD Server application*. Design-time code is only executed in the IDE at design-time (thus the name). Your design-time code should be separated out properly.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, you are right. I divided code into two packages, it's working. Previously, because no ComponentEditor involved, I just put all code into one package.